Stories with hidden/subtle impossibilities or inconsistencies?
There is a certain kind of puzzle story, where the story is seemingly "normal" and perfectly believable, if not for one detail that can't be true (i.e. anachronism, or subtle physical impossibility, or internal inconsistency in the narrative). The point is to find out what's wrong, by spotting the flawed detail.
I know of one such book in Hebrew, called "זה לא יכול להיות" (lit. "this cannot be"). I'm sure there is a whole genre of such stories out there, yet I don't even know how to search for them.
My question is about terminology: is there a genre-name, or search-term, for this kind of puzzle-story?

Nabokov's short story, The Vane Sisters, seems relevant.  That last paragraph really stands alone.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Some mystery stories are like this: solved by the detective's noticing a single inconsistency or impossibility.

The genre of "solve-it-yourself mysteries"  (similar terms include detective puzzles or forensic puzzles) often fall into this category. These types of puzzles are usually presented as a short story, often describing some crime scene or mystery and the resulting investigation/interrogation of suspects. The puzzle is usually solved by noting some inconsistency in the culprit's story which could not have possibly occurred.
